# Iphone cocoa-touch animation suggestions

Tags: iphone

I need a documents or blogs and so on.. I'm realy interesting the animating views, user interface elements on the cocoa-touch king of crash course and how to design them in the photoshop or like that.

I found a few books about describing this subject. As i described the subject i realy need to crash information about these. I know i know, i think and heard somebodies says "you should read a lot of books for achieving this".

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Bill Dudney's [Core Animation for Mac OS X and the iPhone](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bdcora/core-animation-for-mac-os-x-and-the-iphone) has a lot of good info.

Comment: I saw that book and i saw that in the last chapter Bill Dudley is talking about the Iphone animations,  isn't he ?

Comment: He does spend a chapter on iPhone-specific animation issues, but most of the rest of the Core Animation concepts are identical between Mac and iPhone.  The book is a very good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

For a crashcourse in animating views on the iPhone/iPod you basically need to read one chapter within apples developer documentation:

UIView Class Reference -> Animating Views

If you care to jump in even quicker, have a look at code examples like MoveMe.app.

Comment: link to moveme web documentation: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading through Apple's [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/index.html).  In addition to [Bill Dudney's book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bdcora/core-animation-for-mac-os-x-and-the-iphone), it's the best overall resource out there for learning Core Animation.  The [UIView class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) describes how to do UIView animations.

There are a number of good code examples around here dealing with animations under the [core-animation tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-animation).  Additionally, you can search for [iPhone animation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+animation) to find many iPhone-specific animation questions and answers here.  I've learned quite a bit from many of the answers.